# SVN with CruiseControl.NET trunkUrl in ccnet.config

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, cruisecontrol.net

I am new to TortoiseSVN, I have managed to config a project using SVN on my Windows 7 PC.
Now I am trying to config CruiseControl.NET to integrate with SVN to perform the continuous integration and development .

I got stuck with the ccnet.config file, it requires me to provide trunkUrl value.

Both my project and my SVN repository are on my pc for testing purpose, so should I use "file:///F:/Contract Projects/medicaltoolrepository" as the value for trunkUrl.

Here is my ccnet.config contents

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
<project name="Medical Report Generator">
    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger initialSeconds="0" seconds="1800"/>
    </triggers>
    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <trunkUrl>file:///F:/Contract Projects/medicaltoolrepository</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>F:/Contract Projects/Medical Report Generator/ReportGenerator.Web_VS2012_MedicalTheme/</workingDirectory>
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
    </sourcecontrol>   
</project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Can someone tell me where can I get the value for trunkUrl and workingDirectory parameters. My current configuration must be wrong as CruiseControl would not start.
Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The trunkurl would be something like `svn:://localhost/myrepo` or if you're using apache `http://localhost/svn/myrepo`.

and working directory is where you want to check out the repository to on your local disk.

Have you created a repository using `svnadmin create <reponame>` ? You need to do that first. Bring up a command prompt and type 'where svnadmin'. If you don't have it go here http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/